# credentials on publicKey needs for a USB Key everytime

Tags: javascript, webauthn

When i try to login using WebAuthn on `navigator.credentials.get()`.
I need to push some values on property `allowCredentials` because Chrome Mobile it does not allow empty `allowCredentials`.
The hard part is inside the `transports` property, because according to Mozilla documentation, is an array of strings. I have an array of only one string = `internal`, because i don't need a usb or enything else.

```
credencialesPermitidas.push({
  id: base64ArrayBuffer.decode(id),
  type: "public-key",
  transports: ["internal"]
});
navigator.credentials
 .get({
    publicKey: {
      rpId: "localhost",
      challenge: base64ArrayBuffer.decode(response.data.result),
      userVerification: "discouraged",
      allowCredentials: credencialesPermitidas,
      timeout: 60000
     }
   })
```

With these configuration, everything works, but when the process finishes verifying the identity, the result is an error:
[image]

If `transports` is empty, the process needs a USB Key... and I do not understand this point.

Comment: Is it the navigator.credentials.get() call that throws that error but only after you've authenticated using the internal method? Does the UI not let you choose the method if you omit the transport hint?

Comment: The selector was removed as part of the operation. But even with the selector, the fingerprint did not appear.